# cannot restart redmine after config smtp notifcation."Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, redmine

the redmine cannot restart after I config smtp, but it worked fine when I comment the smtp in  configuration.yml, anyone can help me? thanks...

**the smtp in configuration.yml:**

```
production:  
delivery_method: :smtp  
smtp_settings:   
address: "****"  
port: 25  
authentication: :login  
domain: '****'  
user_name: '****'  
password: '****'*
```

**the httpd error log:**

```
App 23280 stdout:  
App 23280 stdout:  
[ 2015-11-04 10:18:36.6100 23162/7eff12d16700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /data/www/redmine: An error occured while starting up the preloader.  
  Error ID: 6206c975  
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-WcAhUb.html  
  Message from application: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 220 column 20 (Psych::SyntaxError)  
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:86:in `load_from_yaml'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:42:in `load'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:67:in `[]'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:24:in `<module:Thumbnail>'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:21:in `<module:Redmine>'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /home/www/redmine/lib/redmine.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /home/www/redmine/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/www/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/passenger-5.0.21/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ 2015-11-04 10:18:36.6157 23162/7eff0cfc5700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:253 ]: [Client 1-3] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 6206c975. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your `configuration.yml` preventing Redmine from reading it. You might be missing some leading whitespace. Remember: whitespace at the beginning of the lines is important in YAML and needs to be preserved. Don't mix tabs and spaces!

Comment: thank you, it's working fine now by your ways.